# cvMatchShapes returns me result which is out of logic

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I'm a newer in computer vision field.

I found some code examples in EmguCV(.NET wrapper for OpenCV)  which I`m trying to use.

Currently I'm working on triangle traffic sign recognition and I'm using cvMatchShapes function.

The function returns "zero" in ideal case, it means that the shapes are the same and the number is

close to zero if shapes are similar.

The problem is that in my case function returns me result which is out of logic.
when function compares triangle with the circle, it returns figure which is less than figure, got
after comparing two triangles.

Here is the function that I use and the images:

```
                double ratio = CvInvoke.cvMatchShapes(modelSignTraffic, trafficSign, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CONTOURS_MATCH_TYPE.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I3, 0);
```

modelSignTraffic - is a template.
In my case it is -

[image]

trafficSign - is an shape that should be compared to the template.

first compared shape-

[image]

second compared shape-

[image]

For the first shape I get ratio 0.55 and for the second shape I get ratio 0.61 .

I would be very grateful if anybody could explain why do I get such illogical result and how  I can fix 
it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why do you think that this result is not logical. Did you read formula for `CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I3`? [Here it is](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#matchshapes). I'm 100% sure that if you calculate this coeficient by hand you will get the same result.

By the way you have to calculate this coeficient for **contours (shapes)** not for images. So firstly detect shapes and after this use `MatchShapes`.

**Update:**

Your solution is wrong. You have to segment red color first and after this use `findContours` to detect red shapes.

Comment: Astor, I detect shapes on the image files with help of canny function.

Comment: Astor,all the shapes are above.First as i wrote I detect them with help of canny func and then I used FindContours method and the last step is cvMatchShapes.

Comment: You don't need Canny in your situation. Simply do color segmentation and find contour. After this use match shapes. You'd better read traffic sign detection articles.

Comment: @Michael do you have any results yet??

Comment: Yes, I was able to get better results. but still the result is far to be ideal.

Image<Bgr, Byte> circleleModel = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("triangle-model.jpg").Resize(200, 200, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, true);

and here is shape to be compared:
Image<Bgr, Byte> tempImage = img                   .Resize(200,200,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR);

I.E. normalization between to images.

Comment: sure,on answer your question?

Comment: Astor,I will post the code tomorrow.Currently I'm a little busy :).

Comment: Astor Hi.
I posted my solution.
Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get better  result from the **cvMatchShapes** function after the images were scaled to same size with help of **Resize** extension.

Unfortunately this solution is not ideal because when checking other options with this approach, I do not always get the desired result.

Here is the code:

```
     Image<Bgr, Byte> triangleModel = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("TriangleTamplate.jpg")
                        .Resize(200, 200, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR,true);
     Image<Gray, Byte> grayModel = triangleModel.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
     Image<Gray, Byte> cannyModel = grayModel .Canny(new Gray(100), new Gray(160));


     Image<Bgr, Byte> comparedImage = new Image<Bgr,Byte>("ImageToCompare.jpg")
                         .Resize(200, 200, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR,true);
     Image<Gray, Byte> grayImage = tempImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
     Image<Gray, Byte> cannyImage = grayImage.Canny(new Gray(100),new Gray(160));

     double eRatio = CvInvoke.cvMatchShapes(cannyModel.Ptr, cannyImage,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CONTOURS_MATCH_TYPE.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I3, 0);
```

For triangle Ratio is 0.0320

For circle Ratio is  0.0829

Comment: Why didn't you edit your question and post an answer? See update of my answer.

Comment: what is the relationship between segmentation by color and using findContours? parameters for comparing shapes must be gray scaled.

i . e, I understand that in order to compare the two forms must be Gray scaled. Or maybe I missing something,please explain.

Comment: Because using this technique you can find the shape (contour) of sign. You'd better read articles about TSD.

Comment: Astor, I implemented as you advised me: