# Why matchShapes gives such small value when it's not supposed to do it?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to match directions (arrows: left, up and so on).
And actually it works quite ok if I want to match some arrow I got from camera with different arrow templates (so arrows are pretty simple objects)
I get result values like 0.005-0.2 (I guess it's pretty good)

But sometimes it also gives pretty low values (says that is a good result) for contours that are very different from my templates (direction arrows), and it also can be 0.2 and even 0.07 I got once (pretty small value)

For example matching those two contours gave good matching value (0.2):

[contour 1 (tempalte).png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDUcA.png) - template image (contour)

[contour 2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fQ2S.png) - some garbage contour (part of `mat` frame I got in `onCameraFrame`)

And one was with 0.07 (I didn't make a screenshot), also was some garbage contour.

Why does it happen?

```
double result = Imgproc.matchShapes(inputContour, templateContour, Imgproc.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I3, 0.0);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cvMatchShapes returns me result which is out of logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122033/cvmatchshapes-returns-me-result-which-is-out-of-logic)

Comment: @Ped7g whatever, there is no answer and at least I gave examples with contours, not just some photos

Comment: yes/no, the point is it is result of some Hu-moment calculation, so if you know enough about it, you can recalculate your contours directly by similar formulas to see why the results are so skewed and similar (eventually you may find some subtle bug in opencv calculating those formulas wrong in certain case, but it's more likely this correct result for those input images, confusing the hu-moment based matching formulas). [Enum of method used](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/df/d4e/group__imgproc__c.html#gacd971ae682604ff73cdb88645725968d) you may also try different methods, if they fit better.

Comment: if you turn the 2nd contour by 180 degrees it is imho "quite" similar to that curved arrow. Not sure whether rotational invariant moments are used here.

Comment: @user924 Matching two shapes always is finding the correlation between them, which results in a probability score between 0 to 1. Hence no matter how oblique any two shapes may be, the score is never a zero, but a very small (negligible) value that is close to zero.